# How to record high quality videos with Windows Media Encoder in C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, screen, windows-media-encoder

I recently created a software for recording screen activity with the help of a windows media encoder tutorial.. However I am having serious problems with quality. It seems the quality of the video is really bad. Does anyone know how I can get around this, I'm guessing it has to be with setting the format of the output, but I don't really know how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Windows Media Encoder is no longer offered for download by Microsoft, so you may want to consider moving to another technology. Without seeing any of your code at all, I can't really comment on anything you are doing. However, I have used WME in the past and can offer a bit of advice. Choose one of the high quality profiles, or consider making your own. I used to use a CBR profile of up to 5000 Kbps to achieve high quality encodes. Note that the higher the quality, the more disk space used. It will fill quickly if encoding a lot of video.

Comment: ok.. thanks.. So please how do I get started with WME? Seems I can't find a nice link myself